# How to code split a svletekit application

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm creating a resume builder where many templates will be possible. I have a component that switches between the different templates depending on what the user chose. For now I only have three templates, but the file already compiles to 300Kb:

```
<script>
    import Student from '$lib/template/_student/Home.svelte';
    import Expert from '$lib/template/_expert/Home.svelte';
    import Artist from '$lib/template/_artist/Home.svelte';

    export let doc;
    $: templateId = doc?.templateId
    $: cssUrl = doc?.design?.color?.substring(1)
</script>

<div id='templateLoader'>
    {#if templateId == '1'}
        <Student {doc} on:modified/>
    {:else if templateId == '2'}
        <Expert {doc} on:modified/>
    {:else if templateId == '3'}
        <Artist {doc} on:modified/>
    {:else}
        <Expert {doc} on:modified/>
    {/if}
</div>

<svelte:head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href={`/css/design.css?t=${templateId}&c=${cssUrl}`} />
</svelte:head>
```

I had an onMount() function that was loading the template dynamically, but that was a very unpleasant user experience (and it's not good for SEO)

I was wondering if it is possible to tell SvelteKit to keep each template in a separate file, and to loda that file with an additional server request () which in SSR is unnoticable) after the `{#if templateId}` section is processed. In Next.js there is a dynamic import mechanism for that.

Any suggestions? I'm planning to have dozens of templates, so I cannot keep things this way.
Just to compare with other comps, this component alone is huge:

> .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/chunks/ToolbarButton-5e81536b.js
> **11.11 kB │ gzip:  3.69 kB** .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/components/pages/authorized/cv/ai/_page.svelte-d03f5080.js
> **14.39 kB │ gzip:  4.99 kB** .svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/chunks/TemplateDetector-88b690e9.js
> **305.29 kB │ gzip: 82.38 kB**

***Ideally, the solution would look like this:***

```
<script>
    export let doc;
    $: templateId = doc?.templateId
    $: cssUrl = doc?.design?.color?.substring(1)

    function getTemplatePath(templateId) {
        switch( templateId ) {
            case '1' :
                return '$lib/template/_student/Home.svelte'
            case '2' :
                return '$lib/template/_expert/Home.svelte'
            case '3' :
                return '$lib/template/_artist/Home.svelte'
            default :
                return '$lib/template/_expert/Home.svelte'
        }
    }

    $: Template = null
        import(getTemplatePath(templateId) /* @vite-ignore */).then(loaded => Template = loaded)

</script>

<div id='templateLoader'>
    <Template {doc} on:modified/>

</div>

<svelte:head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href={`/css/design.css?t=${templateId}&c=${cssUrl}`} />
</svelte:head>
```

But this throws a series of exceptions:

```
            const err = new Error(`Cannot find module '${id}' imported from '${importer}'`);
                        ^

Error: Cannot find module '$lib/template/_expert/Home.svelte' imported from 'C:/Users/zhamd/work/linkedinCv-back/src/lib/template/TemplateDetector.svelte'
    at nodeImport (file:///C:/Users/zhamd/work/linkedinCv-back/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.2.0/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-c167897e.js:54014:25)
    at ssrImport (file:///C:/Users/zhamd/work/linkedinCv-back/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.2.0/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-c167897e.js:53935:20)
    at ssrDynamicImport (file:///C:/Users/zhamd/work/linkedinCv-back/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.2.0/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-c167897e.js:53962:16)
    at eval (/src/lib/template/TemplateDetector.svelte:26:2)
    at Object.$$render (/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@3.59.1/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:2042:22)
    at eval (/src/routes/cv/[id]/+page.svelte:49:147)
    at Object.$$render (/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@3.59.1/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:2042:22)
    at Object.default (/.svelte-kit/generated/root.svelte:102:133)
    at eval (/src/routes/+layout.svelte:26:33)
    at Object.$$render (/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@3.59.1/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:2042:22) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

Comment: In the code above, if I remove the svelte specific $lib syntax, the component is resolved, but I get this error:

Error: <Template> is not a valid SSR component. You may need to review your build config to ensure that dependencies are compiled, rather than imported as pre-compiled modules. Otherwise you may need to fix a <Template>.
    at Module.validate_component (/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@3.59.1/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:2017:15)
    at eval (/src/lib/template/TemplateDetector.svelte:32:59)
    at Object.$$render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Svelte components can be loaded dynamically with standard async import methods (`` await import (`./${yourComponent}.svelte`) ``

Roughly based on your example you could do something of the like, but there's plenty of way to achieve this.
This [article](https://flaming.codes/posts/lazy-loading-modules-in-svelte-to-import-components-on-demand) goes a bit more into detail if needed.

```html
<script>
    const templates = {
        student: () => import('./Student.svelte'),
        expert: () => import('./Expert.svelte'),
        artist: () => import('./Artist.svelte')
    };
    
    let component = 'student';
</script>


{#await templates[component]() then module}
    <svelte:component this={module.default}/>
{/await}
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think about using the #await in the template (as it's forbidden in the root context in script). Awesome solution: now when compiling, I don't even see the TemplateDetector entry in my ouptput files log: it became a tiny part :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just to followup after the answer of Tonton-Blax, this is how I ended up doing it:

```
<script>
    const templates = {
        Student: () => import('$lib/template/_student/Home.svelte'),
        Expert: () => import('$lib/template/_expert/Home.svelte'),
        Artist: () => import('$lib/template/_artist/Home.svelte')
    };

    export let doc;
    $: templateId = doc?.templateId
    $: cssUrl = doc?.design?.color?.substring(1)

    async function loadTemplate() {
        // console.log('loading template ', templateId, ' resume: ', doc._id)
        return await templates[templateId]()
    }
</script>

<div id='templateLoader'>
    {#await loadTemplate() then template}
        <svelte:component this={template.default} {doc} on:modified/>
    {/await}
</div>

<svelte:head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href={`/css/design.css?t=${templateId}&c=${cssUrl}`} />
</svelte:head>
```